# Error in connecting to local mysql in MacOS

Tags: mysql, macos

I am trying this command `mysql -u username -p`. But it returns,

```
mysql: [Warning] World-writable config file '/etc/my.cnf' is ignored.
Enter password:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `mysql-server` instead of `mysql-client`.